# python robo framework - how to sent form data in http request?

Tags: python, forms, http-headers, robotframework

I'm trying to automate the following flow in python robo , using requests 'requests'

`curl -X POST https://localhost:12443/api/customdata/upload/userid/user_values --form "user_data=@user1_data_values"`

`user1_data_values` is the file which will have details of some information which user want to sent to server for processing

I am able to do post request in my automation code without 'form'

```
>>>>> POST request using URL: https://localhost:12443/api/customdata/upload/userid/user_values
06/02/2016 00:00:48 [DEBUG] [user_data] - >>>>> Data in request: None
06/02/2016 00:00:48 [DEBUG] [user_data] - <<<<< Received 200 HTTP code
```

I don't have any clues to how to send the form data & where to keep the file (`user1_data_values`) and how to call the file in test cases.

Answer (score 0):

It has been resolved by doing the following in the code

> > > url = 'http://httpbin.org/post'
> > >       files = {'file': open('report.xls', 'rb')}
> > >
> > > r = requests.post(url, files=files)
> > >       r.text